# Separating SQL, PHP and the view when listing categories and products in Kohana

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-orm

I want to migrate to Kohana with my small websites and I'm trying to separate the SQL, PHP and the view, but I've some problems with this one.

I have to tables. Every category can have multiple products.

**Categories table**

- id
- category

**Products table**

- id
- category_id
- product

This was my previous code (converted to Kohana's query builder):

```
        $categories = DB::select('id', 'category')
            ->from('categories')
            ->as_object()
            ->execute();

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        echo '<b>'.$category->category.'</b><br />';
        $products = DB::select('product')
                ->from('products')
                ->where('category_id', '=', $category->id)
                ->as_object()
                ->execute();

        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            echo $product->product.'<br />';
        }
        echo '<hr />';
    }
```

I want to do the same, just in the view file I don't want to use other than echoing out the variables.

**Update:**
I would prefer a solution without using Kohana's ORM module.
Btw I'm using Kohana 3.0

**Update 2:**

I've accepted Lukasz's last solution, but a few modifications are needed to do exactly what I wanted to (note that this is for Kohana 3.0, while Lukasz was working with an older version):

SQL code:

```
$products = DB::select(array('categories.category', 'cat'), array('products.product', 'prod'))
                ->from('categories')
                ->join('products','RIGHT')
                ->on('products.category_id','category.id')
                ->as_object()
                ->execute();
```

Code in the view file (see comments for explanation):

```
        // Let's define a new variable which will hold the current category in the foreach loop
        $current_cat = '';
    //We loop through the SQL results
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        // We're displaying the category names only if the $current_cat differs from the category that is currently retrieved from the SQL results - this is needed for avoiding the category to be displayed multiple times
        // At the begining of the loop the $current_cat is empty, so it will display the first category name
        if($curren_cat !== $product->cat)
        {
            // We are displaying a separator between the categories and we need to do it here, because if we display it at the end of the loop it will separate multiple products in a category
            // We avoid displaying the separator at the top of the first category by an if statement
            if($current_cat !== '')
            {
                //Separator
                echo '<hr />';
            }
            // We echo out the category
            echo '<b>'.$product->cat.'</b><br />';
            // This is the point where set the $current_cat variable to the category that is currently being displayed, so if there's more than 1 product in the category the category name won't be displayed again
            $current_cat = $product->cat;
        }
        // We echo out the products
        echo $product->prod.'<br />';
    }
```

I hope this was helpful to others as well, if anybody has a better solution go on, share it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$categories = ORM::factory('category')->find_all();

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    echo '<b>'.$category->category.'</b><br />';
    $products = ORM::factory('product')->where('category_id',$category->id)->find();

    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        echo $product->product.'<br />';
    }
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

I assume that you created models for each table? If not, read [here](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/models).

**Better** if you separate data and view layers. And create relations between categories and products in Model files. Then in controller you should call only this:

```
$categories = ORM::factory('category')->find_all();
$view = new View('yourView');
$viem->categories = $categories;
```

And in view file:

```
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    echo '<b>'.$category->category.'</b><br />';

    foreach($category->products as $product)
    {
        echo $product->product.'<br />';
    }
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

You will not have to call 2nd query for every row. Kohana ORM will do it for you. All you have to do is to create appropriate models:

```
class Category_Model extends ORM {
    protected $has_many = array('products');
}

class Product_Model extends ORM {
    protected $belongs_to = array('category');
}
```

**Another approach:** you can join tables categories and products

```
$products = DB::select('categories.category AS cat','products.product AS prod')
                    ->from('categories')
                    ->join('products','products.category_id','category.id')
                    ->as_object()
                    ->execute();
```

And then:

```
$current_cat = '';

foreach($products as $product)
{
    if($current_cat != $products->cat)
    {
        echo '<b>'.$products->cat.'</b><br />';
        $current_cat = $products->cat;
    }

    echo $product->prod.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. I tried exactly the same thing, but I think because of ORM's lazy loading-feature in KO3 the "foreach($category->products as $product)" line would only work this way: "foreach($category->products->find_all() as $product)".

Is there a solution for this without using ORM?

Comment: I've added another approach. Check this.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, I'll accept this as with a few modifications does exactly what I need. I'm updating my question with the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought:

When using the ORM-approach, I think you could achieve the same thing as a join-query using the with() method:

```
$products = ORM::factory('product')
  ->with('category')
  ->find_all();
$view = new View('yourView');
$viem->products = $products;
```

I haven't had enough time to mess around with it, but this is what I would try.